# How can I compress large log files on Windows 2008 Server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, log-files, compression

Some of our log files are > 4GB, and the build-in windows zip will not compress them.

I need to get them off the box, and really don't want to download them uncompressed.  I can't install any additional software on the box since it's a production server.

Is there any way to compress them, or am I stuck with downloading them as-is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could grab a copy of the 7Zip executables and use the command line version without an actual install - just delete the files when complete.

Comment: For the record, you need the .dll as well as the executable.